# Is it true that simple projective modules are injective?

Tags: ra.rings-and-algebras, modules

It is known that simple modules are either projective or singular. Is it true that simple projective modules over (commutative) rings are injective ?

Comment: No, cf. T.Y.Lam, _Lectures on modules and rings,_ Springer GTM 189, Exercise I.3.3.

Comment: what is a singular module?

Comment: @Mariano: An $R$-module $M$ is called _singular_ if $R$ is an essential extension of $(0:_Rx)$ for every $x\in M$.

Comment: @FredRohrer, there are two questions in the question and your comment anwers «No»... to which of the two? :-)

Comment: @Mariano: I see only one question. (Well, if we also look at the title then I actually see two questions that are the same.)

Answer (score 14):

If $P$ a projective $R$-module is simple, then it is a direct summand of $R$ itself (indeed, any nonzero map $R\to P$ is surjective and therefore splits) and is then isomorphic to a minimal ideal $I$ which is projective. $I$ is generated by an idempotent, which is central if the ring is commutative. It follows that $I$ is a direct factor of $R$ as a ring, and therefore $I$ is also injective.

Comment: If the ring is not commutative this breaks down. For example, the ring of $2\times2$ upper triangular matrices over a field has a simple projective which is not injective.

Comment: +1 but I cannot see why $I$ is injective.

Comment: Your ring $R$ is of the form $I\times J$. Since $I$ is a minimal ideal, it is a simple commutative ring, so a field.

Answer (score 4):

If we assume that $\text{Spec}(R)$ is connected, then $R$ is always a field (note the spectrum of a local ring is always connected).  This is equivalent to the nonexistence of nontrivial idempotents.  Indeed, over a commutative ring any simple $R$-module is also of the form $R/\mathfrak m$ for a maximal ideal $\mathfrak m$ of $R$.  Write $R = R/\mathfrak m \oplus I$, for some finitely generated ideal $I$ of $R$.  By the determinant trick, there is an $x\in R$ with $x-1\in I$ such that $xI = I$, hence $I = I^2$.  This implies $I$ is generated by an idempotent, hence $I = 0$, since $R/\mathfrak m$ is nonzero.

Comment: Not quite true, $\mathfrak{m}= 0$ does not follow. The ring just has to contain a field as a direct factor, as per Mariano's answer.

Comment: Once corrected, this is exactly the same as what I did, no? :-)

Comment: Yes, it is!  Hah, alas, I guess that's what you get when rushing through things.

Comment: Though a few added details are never a bad thing :)

Answer (score 0):

No, the cyclic group of order $p$ is not a direct summand in the cyclic group of order $p^2$ ($p$ a prime).

Comment: How does this answer the question?